# ABC.methodname(); as Syntax error on token "methodname", Identifier expected after this token

Tags: java, compiler-errors

- I am new to java.
- I am getting an error at this line ABC.methodname(); as Syntax error on token "methodname", Identifier expected after this token.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my whole code below.

```or-tag-here
    ABC.methodname();

    //ABC.jumpDepositsRecords();

     private static final String AutomaticDeposit_TransferWebServiceClient =
```

Comment: is there a function in `PlayerBallBatchDAO`  class called methodname() ? Please post the code it might be helpful.

Comment: @Ranjith there is not method called methodname in PlayerBallBatchDAO , but there is public List<String> investmentDepositsRecords() when I use ABC.investmentDepositsRecords(); I am getting same error, can you tell me how to fix it...

Comment: does `ABC.jumpDepositsRecords();` work ?

Comment: try with this `public class PlayerBallBatchAWT 
{
    private List<PlayerBallBatchVO> transactionList;
    PlayerBallBatchDAO ABC = new PlayerBallBatchDAO();
 public PlayerBallBatchAWT(){
   ABC.methodname();
 }
     private static final String AutomaticDeposit_TransferWebServiceClient = "ActivityDetection_TransferWebServiceClient";
}`

Comment: @RajithPemabandu it worked thanks

Comment: @RajithPemabandu: I am facing one more problem can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197101/cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-at-this-line-getrecurringfightrequestws-getrecu

Comment: I commented in your new question.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method in the section where attributes of a class are defined...  There's a few options here depending on what you are required to do.

1. Create a constructor and call it in there.
2. Assign something to ABC.methodName such as: private  DFG = ABC.methodname();
3. Perhaps, create a Main method where you call the ABC.methodname()

Comment: @JDDelgado: can you update in my code...its confusing :(

Answer (score 0):

You have a class `ABC` with a method `methodname()`, and you want to call that method from another class.

So, you have to do the functions like object initialisation inside the main method, like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ABC method = new ABC();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look through your code for your `com.sports.jump.laptop.batch.dao.PlayerCatchBallVO` class again. Are you sure that `methodName` is a function, not a field?

Comment: there is no method called methodname in PlayerBallBatchDAO , but there is public List<String> investmentDepositsRecords() when I use ABC.investmentDepositsRecords(); I am getting same error, can you tell me how to fix it...